# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script throw errors:

On Firefox : TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function.

On Chrome : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

I can't track the error when on the website, it's working hosted website but it doesn't working on my localhost.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var container = $('div.alert.alert-danger-1');
// validate the form when it is submitted
var validator = $("#createForm").validate({
errorContainer: container,
errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
wrapper: 'li'
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: jquery.validate requires jquery, make sure the jquery library is included

Comment: @Kld is `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">` not enough ?

Comment: No. You need `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` in front of it - and I strongly suggest you use https for all the scripts, especially if your page is https

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._